# Properly way to import data from external db

Tags: mysql, database, import

I would like to know what is the best way to import data from external db. On my example I want to import orders from web shop to local database. Actually I execute SELECT query on external db with limit 100 and iterate INSERT query to local db until OrderID will not exist. Then I stop importing. Am I doing it right?

Comment: export `order` table and import it into another table of another DB.

Comment: Both databases have a different structure. I would like import only new orders. Not few thousands every time.

Comment: Can't you simply import the orders after a specific date/time? You then store the date/time you're doing the import until your next import and only import those after the last import? Or if you have a fixed time schedule you could simply calculate a time interval based on the current date/time?

Comment: Try synching the schema of two tables and then perform an import to the destination database. An alternate is check out MySQL Workbench, SQLyog, phpmyadmin, etc., that could do some help.

Comment: Synching the schema isn't make sense, in my opinion of course. I have shop on Prestashop. There are distributed tables relations (orders, products, addresses etc.). On my local app I want to keep only few informations like id, actual shop status, weight, address (managing the process of preparing shipments).

@Oceans solution seems to be fine